# regex last child between double brackets {{}}

Tags: regex

I’m looking for some Regex which can find the content between double bracket `( « {{ » and « }} » )`. The contain must not contain double bracket, but can contain simple bracket `( « { » and « } » )`.

Here are some examples:

```
- {{abc}} => abc
- {{abc {{def}} }} => def
- {{abc {{def {{ ghi }} }} }} => ghi
- {{abc {{def {{ ghi{j}kl }} }} }} => ghi{j}kl
- abc => null
- ghi{j}kl => null
```

Comment: `I’m looking for some Regex` ... with nested content like this, you should be using a _parser_, not a regex.

Comment: This regex will get what's between the double brackets into capture group 1 : `\{{2}\s*((?:[^{}]+|([{}])(?!\2))+)\s*\}{2}`

Comment: hi LukStorms :) it does not work with 'a{{var={}}}a' i get 'var={' instead of 'var={}', but it's a very good solution :)

Comment: I agree with you Tim, but i need to have high performance transaction, and i prefer using regex (if possible) instead of parsing :)

Comment: @lepapareil Such side case is a nice example why regex isn't the ideal tool to deal with nested structures. And you didn't tell for that programming language or tool you need this for. So it's unknown if we can use a regex that uses recursion. But with a little tweak also that odd one gets matched : `\{{2}\s*((?:[^{}]+|\}(?=\}{2})|([{}])(?!\2))+)\s*\}{2}`

Comment: I understand. Thks for your help LukStorms :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
{{2}(({(?!{)|}(?!})|\w|[^{}])*)}{2}
```

only get the first group.

Comment: hi Loic :)

it does not work with

- a{{var={}}}a => var={ instead of var={}